# How can I remove the duplicates from answer in O(n) running time?

Tags: c++, hash, time-complexity, duplicates

```
void findodd(int a[])
{
  int hash[100];
  int i;
  int c[100]={0};
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  { 
    c[a[i]]=c[a[i]]+1;
    hash[a[i]]=c[a[i]];
    if(c[a[i]]%2==0)
      hash[a[i]]=0;
  }
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    if(hash[a[i]]!=0)
      cout<<a[i];
}
int main()
{
  int a[] = {1,3,3,5,5,5};
  findodd(a);
  return 0;
}
```

The program is to find the integers which occur odd number of times in the array. Here is the [link](http://codepad.org/ExvhmG9h) to the above program.

Comment: How can I remove the duplicates in O(n) running time?

Comment: Maybe you should put that in the question itself...

Comment: Its there.. the title of the post is the Question itself

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates ? Or find the ones that exist `odd` times ?

Comment: I meant right now my answer is 1555, I want it to be just 1,5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

void find_odd(int a[])
{
    int hash[101] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ )
    { 
        hash[ a[i] ]++;
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
        if(hash[i] != 0 && !(hash[i] % 2 == 0))
            std::cout << i << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,3,3,5,5,5};
    find_odd(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But you might be better of using `std::vector` and/or `std::map`.

---

With negatives : but only in the range -100 -> +100. You cant have a negative array index, so just `+100` to all and have the `hash` array from 0 to 200.

```
#include <iostream>

void find_odd(int a[])
{
    int hash[201] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++ )
    { 
        hash[ a[i]+100 ]++;
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<201 ; i++)
        if(hash[i] != 0 && !(hash[i] % 2 == 0))
            std::cout << i-100 << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {-1 , -1 , -1 , 1 , 3 , 3 , 5 , 5 , 5};
    find_odd(a);
    return 0;
}
```

---

With `std::vector` and `std::map` (works both for positive and negative numbers)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void find_odd_mapped(std::vector<int>& a)
{
    std::map<int , int> hash;
    std::map<int , int>::iterator map_iter;
    std::vector<int>::iterator vec_iter;

    for( vec_iter = a.begin() ; vec_iter != a.end() ; ++vec_iter )
        ++hash[*vec_iter];


    for(map_iter = hash.begin() ; map_iter != hash.end() ; ++map_iter)
        if(!((*map_iter).second % 2 == 0))
            std::cout << (*map_iter).first << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(-1);
    a.push_back(-1);
    a.push_back(-1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(5);
    find_odd_mapped(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @imagi, it checks whether it is even or odd. you could write `hash[i] % 2 == 0` too but this does not work for negative numbers.

Comment: @imagine, you are not using `gcc` are you ? ok will fix.

Comment: @imaginenative, try it now. I changed it to using `%`

Comment: Ya it works for +ve numbers but not for negative and one more question why did you say that using map or vectors would be better? Better running time? With what I have done, the complexity is O(n) right?

Comment: @imaginative, using primitive arrays is more `C`-ish. vectors and maps already offer what you want to do in this example, but with dynamic size. Complexity is still `O(n)` in both ways though. dont worry about that.

Comment: @imaginative, I added a small example for negatives too.

Comment: @Muggen Thanks it works even with  'if(hash[i] != 0 && hash[i] % 2 != 0)'. My only concern here is that the order is n+constant. Even though its just constant, can I do better?

Comment: @imaginative, I think you cannot. Or I do not know anything for that to be honest.

Comment: The `std::map` version is not technically O(n).  (But it's close enough for most practical purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

Given that your algorithm already runs on O(n), I assume you are looking to erase the duplicate entries in your output. One possible solution is:

```
void findodd(int a[])
{
  int hash[100];
  int i;
  int c[100]={0};

  int hashdup[100];
  memset(hashdup, 0, sizeof(int)*100);

  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  { 
    c[a[i]]=c[a[i]]+1;
    hash[a[i]]=c[a[i]];
    if(c[a[i]]%2==0)
      hash[a[i]]=0;
  }
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    if(hash[a[i]]!=0)
      hashdup[a[i]]++;
    if (hashdup[a[i]]==1)
      cout<<a[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Woah never knew this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the only point is if you know boundries for your entries or not, if there is a limited types of input then all the codes above would work but if you don't know the boundries or if the boundries are too high (for example you have an integer range of entries) then even the best algorithm use O(nlogn) to remove dublicate entries.